# Unable to connect GitLab with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm using a self-hosted GitLab instance deployed for the company, along with Visual Studio Code.

I downloaded the extension "GitLab Workflow" in Visual Studio Code, so I can see my GitLab projects hosted in the company instance.

During setup, I entered:

- The company GitLab instance URL "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
- The PAT (personal access token) related to my personal space that contains all my projects.

I also entered the below URL in the configuration file of Visual Studio Code: *Settings* → *Extensions* → *Gitlab Workflow* → *Instance URL* as described in [this article](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow), section: Setup / Step 2:

```
 {
     "window.zoomLevel": -1,
     "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
     "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
     "gitlab.instanceUrl": "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 }
```

But when trying to see my GitLab projects from VS Code, I get this error message:

```
 Failed to parse GitLab API response
 Command failed with exit code 128: git ls-remote --get-url
 fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.
 Error: Command failed with exit code 128: git ls-remote --get-url
 fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.
  at makeError (c:\Users\XXXXXXX\.vscode\extensions\gitlab.gitlab-workflow-3.9.0\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:59:11)
  at handlePromise (c:\Users\XXXXXXX\.vscode\extensions\gitlab.gitlab-workflow-3.9.0\node_modules\execa\index.js:114:26)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Code includes native capability to connect with GitLab.

At *"Start"*, click on **"clone repository"** and then paste the target URL at the navigation bar:

[image: See this picture please]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the extension doesn't know what remote to fetch from GitLab (a configuration issue rather than connection). Try adding this to your `settings.json` file:

`"gitlab.remoteName": "origin",`

If you use a different remote name, then replace "origin" with your remote. You can see the details of your remote using Git:

`git remote`

Comment: Oddly, gitlab.remoteName doesn't appear to have a default value of `origin`. This answer resolved that for me. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like they changed it to gitlab.pipelineGitRemoteName

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on their docs, if you already using Windows you should turn off your  `http.systemCertificates` in VSC `setting.json`

[image]

thanks to this answer [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/245)